# How can I align 5 boxes in a 3x2 layout with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, web-frontend

I'm trying to align 5 input boxes in a 3x2 layout with CSS Flexbox. Three boxes should be on the first row and two boxes should be on the second row. I want every box to look the same with a width of 200px and be aligned with their corresponding box on the other row.

The boxes wrap exactly how I want it to at every breakpoint, but there's [a small misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azmm2.png) on the second box on the second row when it's around 600-700px upward. I don't want to use CSS Grid as a workaround. I've attached my work in the code snippet.

What would be causing that error, and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

```css
.my-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  background-color: #808080;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
}

.new-row {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.spacer {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <div class="new-row"></div>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inputs are self-closing elements. They shouldn't have closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default padding on input fields. I avoid this by just adding a universal selector `*, *::before, *::after { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }` to the start of my document because I always set those attributes on my elements later on and if I don't I would rather the browser not try to do it for me. Also, `<input>` is self closing, you don't need the `</input>`

You could also set it specifically to the input if you want, `input { padding: 0;}` but input isn't the only element with defaults.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.my-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  background-color: #808080;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
}

.new-row {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.spacer {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <input class="item">
  <input class="item">
  <input class="item">
  <div class="new-row"></div>
  <input class="item">
  <input class="item">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `display:flex` sets a flex-item next to each other, when `flex-direction:row`.
- `flex:1` is shorthand property which will keep all child same size.
- You have used `flex-wrap:wrap` which is indeed need when wrapping overflowing flex child.
- Now I have use `:nth-child` selector for selecting first three child.
- `.my-grid .item:nth-child(1) .my-grid .item:nth-child(2) .my-grid .item:nth-child(3)`.
- To set first two `flex-item` in first `imaginery-row` I have used `flex:1 0 calc(33.33% - 2rem - 20px)`.

> `flex:1 0 calc(33.33% - 2rem - 20px)` 33.33% because we need 3 species of 100% `width`, then `- 2rem` gap of `1 rem`  from both side `1rem + 1rem`. and `- 20px` because I have added `padding:10px` to `.mygrid` which is 10px left side and 10px right side so in total 20px.

```css
.my-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  background-color: #808080;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-grid .item:nth-child(1),
.my-grid .item:nth-child(2),
.my-grid .item:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.33% - 2rem - 20px);
}

.my-grid .item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
  <input class="item"></input>
</div>
```